# AngularJS service for php files

Tags: php, json, angularjs

i am trying to create a service for angular which should get the data from a php that generates a json. Right now my service looks like this

```
fixEvents.service('contactService', function($http, $q) {
    this.getallContact = function() {
        var json = $q.defer();
        $http.get('models/contact.getall.json')
            .success(function(data) {
                json.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function() {
                json.reject();
            });
        return json.promise;
    };
});
```

and my controller looks like this

```
fixEvents.controller('contactCtrl', function($scope, contactService) {
    $scope.title = "CONTACT";

    $scope.jsonContact = contactService.getallContact();

    $scope.showMessage = function() {
        alert($scope.jsonContact.length);
    }
});
```

the problem is my jsonContact does not get any result. It seems to be undefined. Is there something i did wrong? And by the way is there a better way to do this ? Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: Hmm..syntax-wise it looks fine. Throw a quick log statement into your `success` function, is the `data` undefined or populated?

Comment: Think you're missing the `.then` in the controller, check this Google group out about this exact topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/UP72qIRo2hI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.then` back in the controller to work with the data:

```
var jsonContactPromise = contactService.getallContact();
jsonContactPromise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.jsonContact = data
}, function(error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, this works great! by the way is there a change to use somehow error after then ?

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel -- Yup, I edited the answer to include the error callback